# Is it Possible to Check-in a DLL When Creating a Branch through Azure Dev Ops API Call?

Tags: azure, powershell, postman, azure-pipelines

I'm wondering if the following is possible is any form. I'm following along with this document: [create-a-new-branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#initial-commit-(create-a-new-branch)) and so far I can create a branch in Dev Ops through Postman with a text commit utilizing:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=5.1
```

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/myfirstbranch",
      "oldObjectId": "b92a68a4cd54506d0d8e264ddddbfe5076dca910"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Updating active tasks, but saving in a new branch.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "edit",
          "item": {
            "path": "/tasks/content/activetasks.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "# My Active Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2\n* Item 3\n* Item 4\n* Item 5\n",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need to be able to commit a DLL on the commit (because my goal is to be able to do this all through a pipeline) and the document says my only values are:

[image]

Is there any way either through this API Call or through PowerShell for me to commit a DLL into the new branch that I am creating? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should **never** put binaries into Git repos. What is your objective here? Binaries should be stored in a system designed to handle binaries, such as Azure Artifacts.

Comment: @DanielMann we have a complicated build process where you need to 5 or so libraries in order to have the APIs build successfully--The objective is to have the DLLs of those libraries check in on a pipeline run (which posts them as artifacts) so that we don't have to build the ~5 libraries locally every time. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Your use-case makes sense, but the process is wrong and will very quickly make your Git repository completely unusable, as Git is not capable of effectively handling binary files -- your repo will rapidly grow in size until it's gigabytes of different versions of binaries. That's why I suggested that you publish your build outputs to a versioned artifact feed, which is **designed** to handle binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the raw bytes from disk then convert to Base64:

```
# locate file
$dllFile = Get-Item .\path\to\dll
# open file stream to read file contents
$fileStream = $dllFile.OpenRead()

try {
  # read file contents into buffer
  $buffer = [byte[]]::new($dllFile.Length)
  $readCount = $fileStream.Read($buffer, 0, $dllFile.Length)

  # convert file contents to base64 string
  $base64EncodedDLL = [Convert]::ToBase64String($buffer, 0, $readCount)
}
finally {
  # clean up file stream handle
  $fileStream.Dispose()
}
```

Now you simply pass the string value stored in `$base64EncodedDLL` as the `content` property and set the `contentType` to `"base64encoded"`

Comment: I'll try this this week!

Comment: @kpolewaczyk That's great, you're most welcome!